# Integer in struct is set to zero

Tags: c, arrays, struct, int

I have written this piece of code, but the output is not what i expect it to be. I set the integer: `proj.startP` to `1000`, but after doing some for loops the variable is set to `0` again.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct vezelstruct{
    float verd[10][10][10];
    int startP;
};

struct vezelstruct proj;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int g, i;

    proj.startP=1000;                           // variable set to 1000
    printf("%i\n", proj.startP);

    for(g=1;g<=10;g++)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
                proj.verd[g][10][i]=0.0;
        }
    }

    printf("should be 1000: %i\n", proj.startP); // it's equal to 0 here
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Index starts from 0!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here: `for(g=1;g<=10;g++)` and here: `for(i=1;i<=10;i++)` you should start from `0` and end with `9`, i.e. `for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)`.

When you try to access `proj.verd[10][10][10]`, you are actually trying to access memory outside the array bounds. which leads to **undefined behaviour**, which in this case resulted in rewriting `proj.startP` to `0`.

Comment: The idiomatic way to write it is `i < 10`, not `i <=9`. No reason to make the code harder to read.

Comment: @Art: You're right. I just wanted to emphasize the number `9` here.

Answer (score 1):

You have overflown your arrays and successfully entered the realm of [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in your case has overwritten other members of a structure. Correct code should be:

```
for(g=0;g<10;g++)
{
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                proj.verd[g][9][i]=0.0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you went out of the bounds of your array and set the value to zero as a result. If you go from 0 to 9 instead of 1 to 10, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you cross the limts of the boundary of the array the compiler tries to replace the value in other part of the stack allocated to you. If that crosses the boundary of stack then you get a segmentation fault. Here since you tried to access more than the array boundary it put 0 in proj.startP.

Comment: if could be better if you add quotation to suport your answers